# Is there an accessible LOG of REPAIR procedure in OpenOffice.org or LibreOffice?

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, repair

I'm developing a PL/SQL tool for Oracle to export a query result set to a ODS file. It seems to work but when I try to open the document, I get the message that something is wrong so OpenOffice ask me to REPAIR the file.

Once repaired, the ODS archive is OK and I can see the content.

Now, I need to figure out what the REPAIR procedure has fixed in order to fix my code.

Do either OpenOffice.org or LibreOffice LOG the REPAIR activity somewhere?

Comment: ods files are zip archives that contain xml data.  You can use an unzip utility to examine the xml data, and might be able to tell what has changed by comparing an unrepaired copy to a repaired copy.

Comment: Of course, I know it is possible and that's exactly what I did. It's just a bit tricky to compare files because of formatting changes. I just reformatted both versions of all files in order to compare them easily. I'm keeping open this question in order to see if anybody will point out a LOG file, though.